# Signed integer array multiplication in two's complement system

Tags: c++, math, bit-manipulation

Unsigned integer array multiplication is pretty straight forward. Let say, you have two integers `a` and `b` and each being 8 x 32 bits unsigned integers. Then you multiply a[0] x b[0] and stores the result in a 64 bits unsigned integer. The lower 32 bits is assigned to the result and higher 32 bits are carried to the next multiplication of item. And you continue until you have multiplied all items in both arrays:

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef std::uint32_t U32;
typedef std::uint64_t U64;

union M64
{
    U64 u64;
    struct 
    {
        U32 lo, hi;
    } u32;
};

void multiply(U32* r, U32* a, U32* b) 
{
    M64 c;
    c.u64 = a[0] * b[0];
    r[0] = c.u32.lo;
    c.u64 = a[1] * b[0] + c.u32.hi;
    r[1] = c.u32.lo;
    // etc......


    c.u64 = a[0] * b[1] + c.u32.hi;
    r[1] = c.u32.lo;
    c.u64 = a[1] * b[1] + c.u32.hi;
    r[2] = c.u32.lo;
    // etc......
}
```

But, how do we do that with signed integers with two bit complement system?

Notice, two bit complement system should be applied to the whole array of integers. Not in every single item in the array.

Comment: FYI: type punning through a union like this is technically Undefined Behavior unless compiler extensions are involved.

Comment: hmm I haven't gotten any UBs so far. Can you explain further?

Comment: @einstein UB includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: Well, UB doesn't mean it won't work, it means it might do anything, including what you are expecting. But on paper, you are only allowed to read from the last field of a union you wrote to (save from some specific exceptions not involved here)

Comment: Ok, do you happen to know any more effective way of doing this instead? Don't know any other way of access the lower bits.

Comment: @einstein `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>` and `std::memcpy()` is the way to go.

Comment: @Frank Isn't that UB as well? Or it requires me to know the implementation of unsigned int.

Comment: `U64 src = 12; struct{U32 lo; U32 hi;} dst; std::memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(dst));` It's not UB because you are explicitely copying bytes around from storage to storage, without involving the type system.

Comment: Re: "how do we do that with signed integers..." how do we do **what**? What do the signed integer values represent, and what do you want the result to be? I read the bit about "two bit complement system should be applied to the whole array..." to mean that the lower-order values are **unsigned**. If you're representing them as signed value you have a big problem. This kind of thing is much easier to do with sign-magnitude representation.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear. two bit complement in the whole array. I think you cannot interpret it differently. If it is signed per item it just won't work I guess. Result should also be two bit complement.

The problem with doing it sign-magnitude representation is that you will have other fallbacks.